Internet is not working after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04
I have just upgraded from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 LTS.
Everything's fine but Internet is not working after being connected.

To get help you have to give as much info as possible, see this https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/ in this case what are you using wifi? does it show in yor setting? how is your tcp/ip setting, and probably some other relevant info.

In my case, I deleted /etc/resolv.conf, renamed /etc/resolv.conf.old to /etc/resolv.conf, and the internet was back. After that the systemd-resolved was installaed to avoid any conflict:
sudo apt install systemd-resolved


Can you explain what systemd-resolved does?

after the upgrade, the work of resolv.conf will replacing with the systemd-resolved  .

Known problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012
The problem was this: /etc/resolv.conf became a broken link along with systemd-resolve.service. I had to delete them both and write a new resolv.conf to fix the error.

Upgraded Dell Latitude from 22.04 to 24.04. No internet. Nothing worked.
I changed /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf to include only
[main]
dhcp=dhcpcd

And then sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
If this solved your problem, let me know. I spent 4 hours & I don't think, it's worth it. But, if this helps then it'll be.
Have a good one.

this worked on my Dell Latitude. thank you.

I had the same issue and I will post my solution because I had to combine two of the above (the problem was indeed the bronken /etc/resolv.conf link):
1 rm /etc/resolv.conf
2 sudo dhcpcd (after this I gained access to internet again, necessary for step 3, but in navbar still looked disconnected)
3 sudo apt install systemd-resolved (after this navbar show me connected and everything was fine)

This solved the issue for me!

This issue is due to a broken symlink on /etc/resolv.conf follow below commands to fix it

rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo dhcpcd

This should fix the problem

If you're encountering this issue, you can check the status of systemd-resolved using the following command:
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service

In my case, it was both inactive and masked. If that's also the case for you, follow these steps:

Unmask the service (only if it's masked):
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-resolved.service


Start the service:
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service


Enable the service (to ensure it starts automatically on boot):
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service



These steps resolved the issue for me.

I have faced the same issue in ubuntu:24.04
following solution is working for me.
internet issue in ubuntu 24.04

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
