No internet connection (both ethernet & wifi) after 24.04 upgrade
I have just updated Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my laptop, and I seem to have internet problems. After both (ethernet & wifi) working in the previous version, I have no internet connection through wifi or Ethernet.
once PC opens it shows connected on ethernet/wifi but no internet
internet only works once I run this command
dhcpcd


So the real question should be why DHCP and or DNS  is not working.

You need dhcp client, not daemon.

@David I don't no why or what should I do

@Mahler any specific command please

ifconfig interface dhcp start

iwconfig for wifi

this error shown dhcp: Unknown server error
@Mahler

See also this previous question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511667/internet-is-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-24-04/1519273
and this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1f7f3rq/my_22_24_upgrade_flopped
